# error while booting

Tags: boot

my device is lenovo thinkpad E14.
processor:intel® Core™ i3-10110U CPU @ 2.10GHz × 4
graphics:intel® UHD Graphics (CML GT2)
i had installed ubuntu 18.04 initially when i had bought it and it was working fine then,after that i tried to upgrade ubuntu to 20.04 but  installation fails.after that it is showing error.[ error]
my laptop is new but still it is showing error while booting ubuntu.
please  tell me what should i do?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dujob.jpg

Answer (score 0):

This particular issue is related to the hardware rather than the OS, and there are a couple of possible solutions:

1. **Confirm the HDD (or SSD) is properly attached**

   The detection error means that the computer cannot physically find the hard drive. This can happen if the SATA connector has come loose through use and is something I’ve seen happen with people who are rather active and mobile with their notebooks.
2. **Factory reset your BIOS settings**

   There are times when the E-series Lenovo notebooks will encounter data corruption in the BIOS. I haven’t figured out what causes this, but one solution is to reset the BIOS settings to their factory default. After the reset, try booting. If the HDD (or SSD) is properly detected, then you can re-apply any preferences you may have configured in the BIOS.
3. **Pull the battery overnight**

   Another somewhat solution that people have done is to pull the battery and leave the machine without power overnight. In the morning, reconnect the battery (and maybe the power cord) then try to boot.
4. **Disconnect the CMOS battery**

   If none of the above items have worked, the final option is to open the notebook, locate the CMOS battery (it will be about the size of a Tylenol pill), and pull it out for 15 seconds. This will clear any corrupted data that might be interfering with the motherboard’s ability to find and use the HDD (or SSD).

Generally this issue is something I have seen only with people who are “very active” with their Lenovos. The storage device can become loose over time if the notebook is carried in a backpack or regularly jostled. In the event option 3 or 4 solves the problem, this points to a situation where the notebook is becoming statically charged, often from a plastic carrying case or regular use on blankets/carpets/etc.

Hopefully one of these options will solve your problem