# ubuntu 20.04 booting issue

Tags: boot

i had installed ubuntu 20.04 on lenovo thinkpad E14.
specification:
processor:Intel® Core™ i3-10110U CPU @ 2.10GHz × 4
Graphics:Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics (CML GT2)
After starting the laptop ,Lenovo logo is appearing after that black screen is showing untill login screen came.also before login screen comes lenovo logo is not showing above rotating wheel while booting[lenovo logo not showing above rotating wheel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dR52j.jpg).
please tell me how can i fix black screen issue while booting and also how can i bring lenovo logo above rotating wheel.
on ubuntu 18.04 booting was fine.

Comment: In [the question you asked just five hours ago](https://askubuntu.com/q/1356641/1222991) you said the upgrade to 20.04 failed. Have you successfully installed 20.04 now? If so, was it done as an upgrade or as a fresh install?

Comment: now ,error has disappeared when i  erase disk and install ubuntu 20.04.but now another problem started

Comment: i had done fresh installation and the error disappears which i had asked 5 hours ago

Comment: @matigo please help me for this problem

Comment: everything is fine,only there is booting problem now which i had mentioned in this question.

Comment: Not really a problem. Some firmwares do not show the vendors logo.

Comment: But when start my laptop ,first lenovo  vendor logo appears after that it also show black screen which is    looking very annoying ,then login screen came.